# Converting int to binary in GUI

Tags: java

I have the assignment to convert an integer to binary for my java class using recursion, and it has to be done within a GUI. I can do it using a scanner and console input and output, but I am having a bit of trouble with the GUI. I have done it in the Netbeans GUI-builder but it won't work, I wrote my own GUI with similar logic, and it won't compile.

I am a beginner and because it is homework I don't want anybody to straight up do the work, I am just looking for a nudge in the right direction. I get the concept, but I tend to make silly mistakes and over think simple problems.

I have searched Stack Overflow, and googled for hours and feel like I am close.
I have a couple of questions, when I am using the Netbeans how am I supposed to pass my output to my textArea, Also is my method in fact a recursive one or did I just use a loop? I am pretty sure that I used recursion if I understood the material.

Please see my attached code: this is the NetBeans WYSIWYG code:

```
     private void jButtonClearActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
            jTextFieldNum.setText("");
            jTextAreaResults.setText("");
    }                                            

    private void jButtonExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
       System.exit(0);
    }                                           

    private void jButtonCalcActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        //get input and set into variables
        int num1;
        num1 = integer.parseInteger(jTextFieldNum.getText());

        if (num1>255 || num1< 0); 
        {
            jTextAreaResults.setText("Please Enter a number between 0 and 255.");
        }

        toBinary(num1);

        public static void toBinary(int num1);
        {
         String r = "";

         for ( int i=0; i<8; i++);

            if (num1 % 2 ==1 )
            {
                r = '1' + r;
            }
            if (num1 %2 == 0)
            {
                r = '0' + r:
            }
            num1 = num1/2;
            jTextArea.setText("Binary Equivaalent is" + r);
        }

    }                                           

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Binary.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Binary.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Binary.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Binary.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Binary().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonCalc;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonClear;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonExit;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelNum;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelResults;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextAreaResults;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldNum;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Here is the code for the GUI that I wrote, I tried to use the same logic, but it looks like I am going about making my inner method wrong? What can I do better, both stylistically and to "grok" it.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


/*This class creates the GUI that we will be using to practice using recursive method calls

 */

public class BinaryConverter extends JFrame
{
    //declare all variables, constants, and components for the GUI

    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel messageLabelNum;
    private JLabel messageLabelR;
    private JTextField boxNum;
    private JTextField boxCalc;
    private JTextArea results;
    private JButton convertButton;
    private JButton clearButton;
    private JButton exitButton;
    private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1028;
    private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 760;

/*
Constructor method for the GUI
 */

    public BinaryConverter ()
    {

        //set title
        setTitle("Binary Converter");

        //set size of the window
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT);

        //build the panel and add it to the frame and display the window
        buildPanel();
        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
    }

 /*
 build panel adds label, text fields and all the buttons to the panel
 */

    private void buildPanel()
    {
        //create the label for the text boxes, the boxes, and the buttons
        messageLabelNum = new JLabel("Enter a Number");
        messageLabelR = new JLabel("Results");
        boxNum = new JTextField(10);
        boxCalc = new JTextField(10);
        results = new JTextArea(20, 80);
        results.setEditable(false);
        convertButton = new JButton("Convert to binary");
        clearButton = new JButton(" Clear Fields");
        exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

        //Group the buttons, and add them to the panel
        add(convertButton);
        add(clearButton);
        add(exitButton);

        //Create a panel and add components to it
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(boxNum);
        panel.add(results);
        panel.add(messageLabelNum);
        panel.add(messageLabelR);
        panel.add(results);
        panel.add(convertButton);
        panel.add(clearButton);
        panel.add(exitButton);

    }


  /*
  Private inner class for event handling when the user clicks buttons
   */

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

            //convertButton, exitButton, and clearButton event handler
            ButtonListener handler = new ButtonListener ();
            convertButton.addActionListener(handler);

            //get input and set into variables
            int num1;
            int result;
            num1 = integer.parseInteger(boxNum.getText());

            if (num1>255 || num1< 0);
            {
                results.setText("Please Enter a number between 0 and 255.");
            }

            toBinary(num1)

        public void toBinary(int num1) {
    }

        {
            String r = "";

            for ( int i=0; i<8; i++);

                if (num1 % 2 ==1 )
                    {
                      r = '1' + r;
                    }
                        if (num1 %2 == 0)
                            {
                              r = '0' + r;
                            }
                    num1 = num1/2;
                    result.setText("Binary Equivalent is " + r);
        }


            clearButton.addActionListener(handler);
            boxNum.setText("");
            boxCalc.setText("");
            results.setText("");

            //action listener for exit button
            exitButton.addActionListener(handler);
            System.exit(0);





    }
    public void main(String args[])
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new BinaryConverter().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    }
}
```

I don't so much like the WYSWYG because I don't follow all of the bloated code that is generated within it, but I got points off last weeks lab for turning in work coded in my own GUI and not using the WSYWYG.

Clarified questions, 
 1. how do I get my output to print to jTextArea I thought jTextArea.setText method would do it.
 2. I guess my most pressing question is how to get my Convert button to work in the netbeans code as that is what I have to turn in.

Comment: You're not attaching the button listener to anything and you seem to have code outside an executable context (like a method or constructor)

Comment: `toBinary` is not recursive. Simply put, a recursive method calls itself. Other than that it's not clear what the rest of the question is to me. Are you just asking for opinions on your code? We don't know why they gave you points off. Unless the assignment was to specifically use a GUI builder to build the GUI that seems like a trivial thing to mark points off for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `>>` and `<<` functions (bit-shift operators). These, combined with you number and the number 1, can be used to achieve what you want. Using recursion, a for loop, or whatever :)